# Why should or shouldn't I use camera2 API in android?

Tags: android

I have made an android application that uses standard android Camera API to take pictures, however i am having difficulty in implementing manual focus and some other features. I have come across Camera2 API recently and just wanted to know if its worth trying or not?

Comment: Should you have grilled cheese for lunch? It depends, do you want grilled cheese or not?

Comment: I love grilled cheese!

Answer (score 7):

On the plus side, the `camera2` API is much richer than the original `Camera` API. I suspect that it will tend to be more stable than the `Camera` API, as I think Google is taking it more seriously. Conversely, over time, manufacturers are likely to invest less and less engineering and QA time on the old `Camera` API. By 2018, when Android 5.0+ is 90% of the market, apps should be using the `camera2` API exclusively, IMHO, unless the app specifically is aiming at legacy devices.

However:

- The `camera2` API only works on Android 5.0 and higher, so unless your `minSdkVersion` is 21 or higher, you still need the `Camera` API for older devices. That means either only using the `Camera` API or using both (and hence having additional engineering work).
- IMHO, the documentation for both is severely lacking, but the `Camera` API has been around longer, so there are more Stack Overflow answers, blog posts, and so on that cover it.
- To *really* take advantage of the power of the `camera2` API, you need to be a camera enthusiast, IMHO. Personally, I am not, and so a lot of what the `camera2` API offers is beyond my comprehension, though I'm sure it's really cool.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer :)

Comment: *Camera2* is so complex yet inconsistent. On my lollipop device it's either stucking preview or weird flash light behavior (on my Sony XPeria and friend's Samsung flash light will remain turning on even after app closed ). *Same* configuration on 2 *different* devices produces *different* result, while 2 *Different* configurations produces *same* result/behavior . Wait , what?? Just shot me on the head. Anyway +1 for the answer.